# Add enough information to the data dump to do accurate daily reputation calculations

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

Currently the data dump does not have enough information to do accurate reputation calculations.  For example, if you cast a downvote on someone else's post the -1 penalty you incur is not recorded in the data dump.  I think there are other issues as well, but that's the one that sticks out at the moment.

Now, there is good reason not to record the individual votes themselves, but you could aggregate it.  Perhaps something like a day-by-day offset that accounts for the difference, recorded in the votes table via a new vote type and new column (OffsetScore).  Of course, I haven't seen your actual schema for recording and handling these issues, and so there might be a better way to do it.  But *something* to allow data dump queries to account for the anomalies would be nice.

Comment: Is stackql up still?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's been down for a while.  I'm moving in < 2 weeks (right before Christmas :( ) and don't have time to spend figuring out why (appearances sometimes to the contrary).  Sorry.

Comment: That said, as soon as I do get time it's near the top of my list.

Comment: It's up again now, but it's not reliable/stable yet.

Answer (score 1):

While I would like to see this I don't think it'll happen. Order of votes matters so the only way to resolve that is to put the timestamp of the vote, which was removed for the risk of de-anonymizing the data dump.

Of course the other way to do this (which I for one would prefer) is to get rid of the silly corner cases in the reputation system (like vote order mattering), but that's been declined in various forms many times already.

I haven't had a detailed look at the data dump but is it possible to figure out which votes were applied against CW posts and which weren't? Remember that a post may change to CW at some point so some votes might give rep and some might not.

More to the point, I can't confirm that the count of hitting the daily rep cap also takes these things correctly into account.

Comment: Regarding order of votes, it is possible to establish the order of votes relative to one another by examining the autogenerated VoteID.  However, exact times would be needed to relate the order of votes related to other events.  CW is a good example, you can't tell which votes are applied before a post became CW as opposed to after, since the time of the CW and the time of the vote are both mapped to the nearest 24 hour block.  Also, the effect of deleted posts isn't easily seen in the data dump.