# Data dump - November

Tags: support, data-dump

It seems to me that statoverflow.com doesn't have the November data (latest data seems to be August), and stackql.net seems to be no more. Are there other [public facing interactive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3422/public-facing-interactive-data-dump) data dumps around?

Incidentally, I can't figure out how to use [this one](http://www.rdbhost.com/rdbadmin/main.html?r0000000767) - the ordering stuff doesn't seem to work, though I hear it's got November's data.

Comment: just load it with so slow only takes 10 mins http://github.com/SamSaffron/So-Slow

Comment: stackql will be back.

Comment: Thanks Joel - I for one really appreciate it!

Comment: @dominic - could you elaborate on the problem you had with ordering at the rdhbost site?

Comment: @pduel - the pointing and clicking interface didn't work for me (the auto-generated SQL just didn't do what I asked - when I told it to fetch me my comments, ordered by `score` desc (by selecting the various rows from the pulldown and checking the `DESC` box) it generated `SELECT * FROM "so"."comments" WHERE "owner" = %s ORDER BY "score" OFFSET 0 LIMIT 30`, which is notably missing the `DESC` parameter. This morning I saw the Edit link by the SQL, and manually editing it returned data fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/creative-commons-data-dump-dec-09/) shows how to get the data up to the start of December. You'll need to figure out how to use the XML yourself though.

[Joel Coehoorn has commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32114) that StackQL is only temporarily down:

> Unfortunately, it's been down for a
> while. I'm moving in < 2 weeks (right
> before Christmas :( ) and don't have
> time to spend figuring out why
> (appearances sometimes to the
> contrary). Sorry.
>
> That said, as
> soon as I do get time it's near the
> top of my list.

Comment: It's actually up again right now, but it's not reliable/stable yet.

Answer (score 0):

A magical unicorn has posted it here, accessible via HTTP: [Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User Data Dumps](http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/)

The naming convention over time has been subject to change, so maybe you are just confused?  The most recent dump, covering to the end of November, was released last week.

Comment: A sparkled unicorn - mir ist schlecht!

Comment: I don't think I'm confused - this question is not about missing data dumps, just that the publicly queryable sources of this data (statoverflow/stackql) don't have the latest data/are down, so I was wondering if there was somewhere else to go that I didn't know about (without the effort of downloading and parsing the dump files myself).

Comment: OK.  That means I was confused.  Sparkle happens.